# VueJS axios.get returns Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I've been debugging this code for a while, without much luck:

```js
async getEvents() {
  try {
    let response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/events/");
    console.log(response);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

The complete code sample is from: https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-make-secure-http-requests-with-vue-and-express/

I receive an error when visiting the site that calls the API endpoint:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createAxiosError (utils.js?c786:148)
    at Object.settle (utils.js?c786:127)
    at handleRequest (handle_request.js?da0c:126)
    at eval (index.js?94db:26)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MockAdapter.eval (index.js?94db:25)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js?5270:52)
```

If I just copy the url (http://localhost:8000/events/) in the browser I receive the correct data. I have tried with and without trailing slashes.
Am I misunderstanding the error message, and should I look elsewhere?

Comment: A 404 usually indicates that the resources was not found. Have you added any previous setup to your Axios instances? like the baseURL?

Comment: Thank you so much, it was exactly the BaseURL, that was wrongly set to another value elsewhere. Spend hours starring at this :) Leave an answer, and I will mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: Great!, yes that can cause issues. I did add a response but it seems that you already accepted another response as the correct one. Anyhow, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In computer network communications, the `error 404` indicates that the browser was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested, in other words, the `request url` did not exist. So you want to double-check that.

Solution: Go to the `network` tab, click on the error request, inside the `Headers`, you can see the actual `request url` which has been sent to the server.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I have a similar issue and I looked up the Request URL as you wrote, but what do I do to solve the error, I dont understand what's wrong? If you want to check my question out that would be very appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70624916/7109256

Answer (score 0):

A `404` usually indicates that the resources was not found. Have you added any previous setup to your Axios instances? like the baseURL?
Most of the time the `BaseURL` is set to on an Axios instance that can cause confusion and issues.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue, then just added in my catch(vuex) `error.response`