# Error: Request failed with status code 404, React, Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, nodemailer

I have built a form which I want to be able to send emails, to do this I have attempted to follow this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3-By9QfFa0

However I am running into an issue where I am getting the error in the question title which is coming up in my console web browser when trying to submit the form. I realize the issue might have something to do with one of the routes somewhere but I just cant figure it out (unless it's something completely different).

schoolForm.js

```
const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
e.preventDefault();
try { //I also tried using only: "/send_mail" here like I have in server.js but it didnt work
  await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/send_mail", {
    name
  });
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  }
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.post("/send_mail", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  let {text} = req.body;
  const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: "someone@hotmail.com",
      pass: "password"
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });

 await transport.sendMail({
    from: "someone@hotmail.com",
    to: "someone@hotmail.com",
    subject: "subject",
    html: `<p>${text}</p>`
  })

});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on port 4000");
});
```

**Edit: The error I get in the browser:**

[image]

Is there anyone that can help me solve this issue? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your react app is runing in wich port ?

Comment: What is an error message?

Comment: @OmarBerrami http://localhost:3000

Comment: @jkaczmarkiewicz I don't know what your question is? The error message I am getting, is the one in the title: Error: Request failed with status code 404

Comment: @random1234 your problem is that your node app is runing on port 3000 and also your react app is runing on port 3000 so change one of theme

Comment: @OmarBerrami No changing it didn't work, I added a screenshot of the error I'm getting however, maybe that will help?

Comment: React default running will be on port 3000. And your server is also running on port 3000, change the port of your backend server, and Make sure if both of them are running properly!!

Comment: @MuhammedRahif Omar already told me to change the port, I changed the server port to 4000 but still it wont work.

Comment: Then please edit the question as well, otherwise people like me will say this issue again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server is listening on port **4000**. // server.js

```
app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on port 4000");
});
```

You should use below **URL** for Axios call. // schoolForm.js

```
await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/send_mail", {    // use port 4000 not 3000
    name
});
```

Comment: It actually worked, thank you, however, do you know why my `req.body` is giving me `undefined`?

Comment: Are you sure that req.body is undefined? Please check once again `app.post("/send_mail", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  let {text} = req.body; //use {name} instead`

Comment: Thank you so much, I replaced `{text}` with the variables I was sending from the front-end `{name}` etc... and it worked, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You've set up your server to listen to port 4000 but your `axios` request is to port 3000.
Make sure you send the request to the correct port:

```
await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/send_mail", {
    name
  });
```

Also note the `body-parser` is deprecated and you should use `express` built-in middleware. so instead of:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

you should have:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
```

and you can remove `body-parser` dependency.

You can read [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) to learn more about express built-in middleware and their optional properties.

EDIT:

The reason it wasn't working is because `body` is an object created by the middleware itself. Therefore `req.body` is `undefined` since the `body` object doesn't exists

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, it did work, however Alpesh Patil gave the same answer and he wrote his before yours, therefore I awarded him the bounty and accepted his answer. I do appreciate you also informing me of the deprecation of `body-parser` though.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this issue though? Do you know why my `req.body` is giving me `undefined`?

Comment: No worries, I'm here to help not to collect points :) 
The reason it wasn't working is because `body` is an object created by the middleware itself. Therefore `req.body` is `undefined` since the `body` object doesn't exists.